# unable to access microsoft.entityframeworkcore.Tools?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

[nuget.org] Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trop9.png)

Comment: Are you on a company network that needs an HTTP proxy to access websites outside the company's own network?

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing,
You have to go to NuGet packet manger and add package source called NuGet Org.
You have to install the NuGet Org package to overcome this error.